# Barcode readerview comes twice after scanning so many times in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, barcode-scanner

I have an IPad application which is using barcode scanning.I am using ZBarSDK for scanning the barcodes.Like this i am presenting the scan view.`

```
// ADD: present a barcode reader that scans from the camera feed
        ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
        reader.readerDelegate = self;

        reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

        reader.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        //reader.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;

        reader.cameraOverlayView=cameraOverlay;

        if( [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:                         UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront ])
        {
            reader.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
        }
        ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;

        reader.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
        // TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

        // EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance

        [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                       config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                           to: 0];
        reader.showsZBarControls = NO; 
        // present and release the controller
        [self temporarilyHideStatusBar];  
        if(fromscan==YES)
        {
            [self presentModalViewController:reader animated:NO];
        }
        else
        {
            [self presentModalViewController:reader animated:YES];
        }

        [reader.view addSubview:back];
        [back addTarget:self action:@selector(backpressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [reader release];
```

followed by

```
 - (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    // ADD: get the decode results
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
    [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)
        // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
        break;

  //commented blues  
    NSLog(@"%@",symbol.data);

     [self sdsdsd:symbol.data];

     [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}
```

sdssd is my function for taking that data.All r working perfectly.But my problem is after scanning for sometime when the button pressed for scanning an overlay is coming but was not allowing the scan ,with  a varying green boarder inside that overlay.when we cancel that is showing like the scan is already done.that is it at the next page where i am going from scan. Can anybody knows why this is happening?

Comment: I think your app might have actually loaded the Scanner controller twice in a row causing the scanner to appear like its not working. Try adding a boolean flag to do something like if(!scannerVisible){ scannerVisible = YES; [self showScanner]; } to prevent double ups.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
- (IBAction) scanButtonTapped
{
    // ADD: present a barcode reader that scans from the camera feed
    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    reader.readerDelegate = self;
    reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
    // TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

    // EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                   config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                       to: 0];

    // present and release the controller
    [self presentModalViewController: reader
                            animated: YES];

}

- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    // ADD: get the decode results
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
    [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;

    for(symbol in results)
        // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
        break;

    // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode data
    resultText.text = symbol.data;

    // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode image
    resultImage.image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // ADD: dismiss the controller (NB dismiss from the *reader*!)
    [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

Comment: wat is this...removed all my conditions?